# Fill Datasets with data in a specific time range

Tags: dataset, data-analysis, anylogic, energy

I have a simulation that determines the energy requirements of a factory over the period of one year.
The energy data of the whole year is in one data set after the simulation went through. Now I want to copy the existing data in a new data set, but only for a specific time period, for example from June 1 to June 31.
I use the following code for this:

```
specificDatasetJune.setCapacity(monthCapacity); //"specificDatasetJune" gets capacity of the time period, e.g. June    
specificDataset.fillFrom(datasetTEST); //Data from fill dataset "datasetTEST" is copied to the "specificDataset".
```

My problem with my current functions is, that with the function "fillFrom" I cannot specify a time period, because it copies all data from the original data set. If I use this code for example in June, my new dataset gets values from June till December. If I use the code after the finished simulation I only get the data for December.
But I want to copy only a specific time window. Is that possible?

I used the following help page from Anylogic:

> anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/analysis/DataSet.html

Best,
Christoph

Comment: Hi, tried it. My focus is to fill the new data set only with data over a specifc time period, if possible after the simulation is finished, to analyze the data as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) fill the new dataset manually. Simply loop over the original dataset and copy only the bits that you need. Assume the original ds copied data each day, then the x-values are days:

```
int startDay = 10; // start Jan 10
int endDay = 30; // end Jan 30
ds_Copy.reset(); // delete any old data
ds_Copy.setCapacity(endDay - startDay); // prepare for new data
for (int i=0; i<ds_Original.size(); i++) {
    if (i>=startDay && i<endDay) {
        ds_Copy.add(i, ds_Original.getY(i));
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can do this at any point in time, be it June or at the end of the model. Just make sure the `endDay` has actually passed already